# null column change datatype

Tags: c#, database, datatable

I am getting a datatable from my DB with one NULL column. By default the datatype is Int32.
If I change the datatype like below it says:

> Cannot change DataType of a column once it has data

```
_object.datatable.Columns[coll].DataType = typeof (decimal);
```

Is there a way to get the column as decimal or to change the datatype in the code ?

Comment: Where is this table coming from? Are you building it in memory? If so, change the type where you build it. Are you getting it from a database result? If you are, are you sure it is even appropriate to give it a different type? (If it is, is it more appropriate to change it in the database.)

Comment: i am getting the datatable from a stored proc. I need a blank column in UI so getting one like NULL AS 'Test'

Comment: If you need a blank column, can you not simply add one with the appropriate type. `table.Columns.Add("Test", typeof(decimal));`

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on this several times.

You have three options.

1. Create the columns by yourself

   ```
   var table = new DataTable();
   table.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
   table.Columns.Add("col1", typeof(decimal));

   DataAdapter.Fill(table);
   ```

if you use a DataAdapter or DataReader to fill a table, the columns are only created automatically if you haven't done it by yourself before

1. If you need a different DataType for a relation, just add an expression column

   ```
   table.Columns.Add("col1_decimal", typeof(decimal), "col1");
   ```

that column will be readonly, but will work for Relations.

1. Add another column, copy the data, drop the first column, rename the new one

   ```
   table.Columns.Add("tmp", typeof(decimal));

   foreach(var row in table.Rows())
       row["tmp"] = row["col1"];

   table.Columns.Remove(table.Columns["col1"]);
   table.Columns["tmp"].ColumnName = "col1";
   ```

this could be a performance bottleneck for many rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can't autoconvert the entire column to the new datatytpe.

You can convert a specific value when rou read it:

```
decimal dec = (decimal)(int)_object.datatable[rownum][col1];
```

Note: if the real value is an Int32, you need to unbox it by casting to int, before you can cast to decimal.

Comment: He had another question (now deleted) where he was trying to stuff 3.11 into an integer column. The problem isn't reading so much as it is storage.